# Finishing details on a JUnit 4 dynamic suite

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

Hi – I wanted to automatically sweep JUnit tests into suites as part of my continuous builds, so I derived a runner from JUnit's Suite which finds all test classes in a package. The runner works just fine, but the results display is less than expected.

I have one class in my testing support package with a @RunWith annotation for my runner. The runner works by reading a property to get the package under test. Set the property and tell JUnit to run the annotated class, and all tests in that package are executed. The name of the suite is reported as the name of the class which has the @RunWith annotation, in both Ant and IntelliJ. My runner has an override for ParentRunner.getName() which returns the name of the package under test. I verified that the string gets into the runner's Description object. What am I missing?

Environment:

- JUnit: 4.5
- Ant: 1.7.0
- IntelliJ IDEA: 8.1

Thanks for whatever direction you can provide.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Which details are you missing? What do you want to see? Feel free to edit the question to provide some information.

Answer (score 1):

This is because ANT and IntelliJ use their own runners, so they are building the name based on the test, and not getting the name from your runner. In other words, the runner is delegated to for the purpose of running the test, but not for the purpose of describing it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem just a few weeks ago and created an open source project because of it.

You may include it via maven

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.cschoell</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit-dynamicsuite</artifactId>
   <version>0.2.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

or download it from the github page, where you will find its documentation as well.

https://github.com/cschoell/Junit-DynamicSuite

There is a Junit runner included which allows to scan either a directory or the classpath for unit tests and filter them by implementing a simple interface.